# Relative velocity before and after photon exchange

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

An atom has rest mass $m$ in the ground state and $M$ in an excited state.  Two of these atoms are travelling towards each other, one in an excited state one in the ground state.  The excited atom decays, emits a photon which gets absorbed by the ground state atom.  Show the relative speeds are unchanged.  It then asks to work out the relative speed.

So I have several questions about this:

1) how is it absorbed? Sure it gets doppler shifted and hence will not get absorbed (or will make the atom raise to an even higher rest mass)?

2)Surely the relative speed doesn't change.  If they are both at rest, one fires a photon and the other absorbs it, they will both be moving away from each other.

Comment: Work in the centre of momentum frame, then the atoms start by approaching, swap a photon and end by retreating. The before and after situations are the same just with the atoms swapped over.

Comment: Thats what I thought, however the question asks us to find the relative speed (that argument surely works for any relative speed).  

Also, why doesn't my point 2 hold?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to work out the relative speed

Comment: The relative speed is changed. If the atoms are both at rest initially then they will be moving apart by $2(M-m)c$ finally.